# RESTRICTED_USER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-administration

Before changing database schema I issue:

```
ALTER DATABASE SET RESTRICTED_USER
```

On completion:

```
ALTER DATABASE SET MULTI_USER
```

I understand that a running transaction will be permitted to continue until completion.

Q: Is there any way to wait till all regular users are off the database?

Q: Can the regular users issue more transactions? Can they continue working until disconnected from the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From SQL Server Books Online

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933082(SQL.80).aspx

> If the termination clause is omitted,
>   the ALTER DATABASE statement waits
>   indefinitely, until the transactions
>   commit or roll back on their own.

So SET RESTRICTED_USER will wait until all transactions have completed before taking affect.

Once in place, regular users cannot issue further transactions, only members of the db_owner fixed database role and dbcreator and sysadmin fixed server roles can connect to the database.

Comment: that means the regular users remain connected to the server but have no access to restricted db?

Comment: Users are disconnected from the specific database. Access to other databases is available as normal.